# Undefined control sequence \textb

Tags: errors, page-breaking

I used the following code to create newpage and bold the subject that is start in the new page.

```
\newpage{\textb{Appendix B}}
```

[image: Appendix B]

But I don't know why I got the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.

 l.322 \newpage{\textb
                     {Appendix B}}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

File: images/image.png Graphic file (type png)
<use images/image.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: images/groningen.png  used on input line 395. on input
 line 395.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 56.9055pt x 18.8136pt on input line 39
5.
```

Can someone tell me how I can fix it? I want to remove this error. I tried different solution but what's wrong with the above code?
I want to have appendix in newpage and in bold format. Any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You use `\textb`  instead of `\textbf`. That's the error.

Comment: You should not need to write `\textbf{Appendix}` ever. Use proper markup as for example `\section{}` and the like to start a new section or subject. Also with correct setup this section could be enumerated with "Appendix B" so that `\section{Foobar}` would yield "Appendix B: Foobar" or something like that.

Comment: Also `\newpage` doesn't take an argument and `\textbf{Appendix B}` is nothing you'd have to group, so better syntax would be `\newpage\textbf{Appendix B}`.

Comment: And for the future to help you better understand errors raised by TeX: The last token before the line break is the one TeX had an error with (either during its expansion or because it is not defined). So from the line break of your particular error message you can tell that `\textb` is the cause of the issue as it is the last token prior to the line break.

Comment: your title is misleading: the error message you show does not say `\newpage` is undefined it says `\textb` is undefined.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I changed it to \textbf and the error disappeared. I didn't want to use \section for my appendix. I wanted to have appendix without section number! I used \newpage \textbf instead of that. Best.

Comment: @Skillmon If I used \section then my Appendix will have number. something like this: 8 Appendix, Am I right? I don't want to have number before the Appendix

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. I edited the topic and changed it to \textb

Comment: @nhh then put an `\appendix` before the start of your appendix. And if that doesn't help, ask a specific question how to get the formatting you need including a small minimal (non)working example that includes your `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` and some dummy content, so we get something to play with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been caused by a typo.